# Android classic IRC-like chat box

Tags: android, android-layout

I dread designing UI for Android apps, and I have been searching and trying every possible combination of things to get this the way I want it, but I just cannot seem to get it right.

I want to have a simple Android app that has a text field and a send button next to each other on the bottom of the screen (I already have this correct), and I also want a functional chat area filling the rest of the screen above.

It obviously needs to be scrollable, and I would like to be able to add a new line to the bottom of the chat by doing something like `chatBox.add(username, text)`.

This is the type of view I am looking for:

```
<bob> my name is bob
<bill> hi bob, my name is bill!
<bob> we are having an awesome conversation, bill
<bill> both of our names start with a b
<bob> how right you are
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had made such app. For chat window I used listView. ListView has stackFromBottom mode. So the last added messages will be on the bottom of ListView. Also I created custom Adapter extending ArrayAdapter, so it is easy to add new messages.

Here is [a nice example](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listviewarrayadapter-and.html), how to use listView with adapter and add new items.

Comment: Thank you so much for that article it helped a lot, I'm currently going to +100 your answer but I'm going to wait a few days and see if anyone else wants to contribute first.

Comment: I think all answers will be base on listview. Also you can use custom listview classes e.g. "endless" listviews or "drag to refresh" listviews which you can find on github. Depends on your design.

Comment: Okay, I'm just gonna go ahead and +100 you instead. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can wait as long as you wish, maybe someone has better ideas )

Comment: Every time I change screen orientation all the messages in my `List<String>` are wiped off the view.

Comment: Yeah, this is android default behavior when configuration got changed (destroy activity and create new one). [read it](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html). You should restore message list or tell android not to kill activity but just rotate it.

Answer (score 2):

Leonisdos is right, you shoud use listView. Do you know the app Irssi-ConnectBot ? I think you should have a look in its source code to have many good examples.

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/irssi-connectbot/) the code.google project of Irssi-connectbot (and the [github](https://github.com/irssiconnectbot))

Answer (score 0):

Wrap a `TextView` in a `ScrollView`. Use `append()` on the `TextView` and `fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN)` on the `ScrollView` when you append new chat entries.

For longer chats, Leonidos' `ListView` approach is more efficient, but I thought I'd mention this one.